# Was affray a common law offence before it was codified in statute?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-history

Section 3 POA 1986 describes affray as a criminal offence. What was the status of it before this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Yes, affray was an offence at common law.

Read [the introductory text of the Public Order Act 1986](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/introduction):

> An Act to abolish the common law offences of riot, rout, unlawful assembly and affray and certain statutory offences relating to public order ...